# Is there any free, open-source alternative for MATLAB to do frequency analysis?

Tags: open-source, image-processing

MATLAB is an expensive and vey elaborate software out there. Is there any free, preferably open source, software near MATLAB; at least offering some features of MATLAB in FFT, and other frequency analysis tools?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. To be more specific of what you can do to improve this Q: list the specific features you need.

Comment: Frequency analysis and FFT are rather trivial and also quite broad. Can you be more specific to what you need?

Comment: related http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/194/free-alternatives-to-matlab-that-run-on-linux

Answer (score 5):

There are two free alternatives to MATLAB with Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) that I'd like to recommend based on my own usage:

- R
- Python's Scipy package

**R Statistics**

[R is a statistical analysis software. It is very very good at statistics and data visualization.](http://www.r-project.org/)

[Here's some discussion on Stackoverflow of various packages that allow FFT in R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010605/fast-fourier-transformation-in-r)

**Python**

[Python is a general purpose programming language](http://www.python.org/), and it's [Scipy package](http://www.scipy.org/) has grown functionality that is nearly comparable to R. [Stackoverflow has a great example of FFT frequency analysis in Python's Scipy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456037/scipy-numpy-fft-frequency-analysis)

**A third option, Octave**

[Octave is an interpreted language environment that is quite similar to Matlab.](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) I have not used it, but I did a full feature analysis when I decided on using R, and Octave came in second.

Here's Octave's FFT functionality: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Signal-Processing.html

Pick the one that best represents the direction you're heading. R is great for statistics, Octave is more pure math. Good luck!

Comment: Can you add any personal experiences with this software?

Comment: I have used R and been to many presentations on it and using it. Octave, not so much, but it was second to R when I was doing a package analysis for my own needs.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! To join in to what Kelly was referring to: Could you please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer? A.o., please include essentials from behind off-site links – as if the linked pages disappear, this information would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to playing with relatively new languages, have a look at [Julia](http://julialang.org/).

As a Matlab user, you might find it familiar.

Its FFT function is documented [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=fft#Base.fft); cosine transforms, filters and convolutions are also part of its standard library. Interestingly, there is also a [paper](http://web.mit.edu/lhoang/www/pfft.pdf) describing how to make use of Julia's parallelism to implement a parallel FFT.

In particular, it implements most of the [Matlab functions for Fourier Analysis](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/fourier-analysis-and-filtering.html), and also gives you control of whether to perform the transform in-place or not.

It is built on top of the [FFTW C library](http://www.fftw.org/), so its performance is predictable and state of the art. (Note you can also interface FFTW [from Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are many good alternatives for MATLAB:

[Octave](http://www.octave.org)  Octave has a syntax that is virtually the same as MATLAB's and it is therefore very easy to get started with. It  allows the implementation of functions in the C language, which greatly outperforms all script implementations.

[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/SciPy)
Use python as a language to MATLAB and, for plotting at least, the syntax is close enough to MATLAB's to be simple to get you started.

[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) The graph plotting quality of matplotlib is among the best I've come across and I've found nothing that compares to its tools for scrolling and zooming around data plotted on a graph.

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is a free open-source mathematics software system licensed under the GPL. It combines the power of many existing open-source packages into a common Python-based interface.